# Html Encode getting double Encode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am calling @Html.Encode to encode the `<` sign but my output is `&amp;lt;` should I be calling the Html.Encode method to clean the string?

Code

```
<span>@Html.Encode(indication.Sentence.CompiledTextTitleCase)</span>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For displaying the "Ph-negative Adolescent and Young Adult or Ph-negative Adult: Age < 60 years" you have to simply provide

```
<span>@indication.Sentence.CompiledTextTitleCase</span>
```

[image: result]